# Pass content from build back into Visual Studio Team Services Build

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am running build on Azure with a custom build agent (using Unity3d to be precise) I generate output of the build within a .txt file on the build machine and would like to include content within work items created during build.

Example:

1. Unity build fails and an error is logged to Build.log.
2. New bug is created with reference to build and the error message from the
   logfile

Right now I am using a powershell script

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\BuildProjectPC\Build.log")
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=logContent;]$content"
```

To format the bug i use `System.Description = $logContent` but the content of the variable from PS does for some reason not end up in the bug item (it just contains "$logContent").

Any idea or direction how to fix this, respectively how to feed info back into vsts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable value that used for creating work item is initialized before running build steps, so you can’t specify a dynamic variable or change the variable value during the build step that used for creating work item.
You can follow up these steps to verify it:

1. Open your build definition > Variable > Add a new variable (e.g. logContent, value: oldValue)
2. Select Options > Check Work Item on Failure > Additional Fields > System.Title $(logContent)
3. Add PowerShell build step: Write-Host "$(logContent)"
4. Add PowerShell build step: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=logContent;]newValue"
5. Add PowerShell build step: Write-Host "$(logContent)"
6. Add PowerShell build step: [Environment]::Exit(1)

The log result:

1. Step 3 output oldValue
2. Step 5 output newValue
3. The created work item title oldValue.

The workaround for your requirement is that, you can [create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) and [associated to build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link) through PowerShell with Rest API (add PowerShell step at the end of other steps and Check Always run option).

Associate work item to build:

Request Type: Patch

Request URL: https://[your vsts account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[work item id]?api-version=1.0

Content-Type:application/json-patch+json

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///Build/Build/[build id]",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Making a new link for the dependency"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can refer to this blog for PowerShell scripts to create and associate work item.

[Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/)

Comment: Thank you, that looks very promising. I was able to get the linked build association article to work, but have quick follow-up question: How would I make sure to only run this on build failure? (As far as I understood I will create a new ticket manually instead of using the 'Options' way and associate all values I need. This should only be done on build failure though)

Comment: @floAr The easy way is to check whether there is error in Build.log (your $content) in your PowerShell script, if so create and associate work item to build, if not, skip.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get an initial solution using your answer and will be able to build upon this!

Answer (score 0):

In the Additional Fields you need to reference the build/release definition variable with the following notation:       `$(logContent)`

as shown here below:

[image: reference to build variable]